# Application specific environment on the same server in Nginx/Passenger

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have two Rails applications (say app1 and app2) deployed using Nginx/Passenger. The server definition in nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
        rails_env demo;
        client_max_body_size 50M;
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root /data/apps;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_base_uri /app1;
        passenger_base_uri /app2;
    }
```

You can see that both are configured to use `demo` as the `RAILS_ENV`. How should I change my configuration to run both the apps in different environments. Let's assume app2 is suppose to run with `RAILS_ENV=qa` and app1 with `RAILS_ENV=demo`

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding location statemants for the paths like

```
location /app1 {
    rails_env demo
}

location /app2 {
    rails_env qa
}
```